# Why does PyAudio Work in One Module but Not Another?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, wave, librosa

I apologize ahead of time for my lack of ability to phrase this, but I have a question regarding imports. I’ve been creating an app that displays flash cards with musical note names on them, and have also created an audio component that records and writes the user playing a note to a .wav file.

Anyway, the audio functions return a note name calculated from the frequency of the recorded note. I know these functions work because I’ve tested them with my guitar probably 150 times lol.

In another file, I imported these functions i.e. “from x import y, z”. I created the flash cards with TKinter, put some lag time between them, and wrote a little while loop to keep everything going continuously.

Well, when I call the imported audio function and play my guitar to record the note, nothing is being recorded. It’s just air. Again, this doesn’t happen if I do this in the original file. So naturally, my app is telling me the notes are all wrong....

My question is, do I need to import all the audio modules over to the flash card module? I used PyAudio to record the guitar sound in the audio modules, so do I need to import PyAudio to my flash card module, too? I’m pretty sure the answer is no, but I can’t think of why it consistently works when I run it in the original module I created and it records air when I import it to the flash card module.

To try to be more clear, I imported the audio functions I created over to the flash card module....but do I need to import all the libraries I used to create those audio functions, too?

Again, sorry for not being able to articulate it better! :)

Below is code for the audio portion:

#File 1:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import librosa

def read_and_write_audio():
    CHUNK = 1024
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100
    seconds = 3
    filename = 'test.wav'


    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                    channels=channels,
                    rate = fs,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                    input=True)

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(fs / CHUNK * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


    wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()

    return filename

def get_pitch(filename= read_and_write_audio()):
    x, sr_ = librosa.load(filename)
    pitches, mags = librosa.piptrack(y=x,sr=sr_)
    index = mags[:,128].argmax()
    pitch = pitches[index, 128]
    note_name = librosa.hz_to_note(pitch)
    
    if len(note_name) > 2:
        return note_name[0:2]
    return note_name[0]
```

#File 2: Flash Card portion

```
from pyaudio_test import read_and_write_audio, get_pitch
import tkinter as tk
from pil import Image, ImageTk
import random
import os
import time


def display_note_flashcard():
    root = tk.Tk()
    folder = 'C:/Users/superuser/Music_Flash_Cards/chromatic_note_cards'
    filename = random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
    note = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, filename))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(50,50, anchor='nw', image=photo)
    
    root.after(10000, root.destroy)
    root.mainloop()
    
    return note


def display_correct_card():
    card = tk.Tk()

    folder = 'C:/Users/superuser/Music_Flash_Cards/correct_and_incorrect_cards'
    correct_card = 'Correct.PNG'
    
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, correct_card))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(card, width=400, height=400)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(50,50, anchor='nw', image=photo)

    card.after(5000, card.destroy)
    card.mainloop()


def display_incorrect_card():
    card = tk.Tk()

    folder = 'C:/Users/superuser/Music_Flash_Cards/correct_and_incorrect_cards'
    incorrect_card = 'Incorrect.PNG'
    
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, incorrect_card))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(card, width=400, height=400)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(50,50, anchor='nw', image=photo)

    card.after(5000, card.destroy)
    card.mainloop()



def main():
    while True:
        x = display_note_flashcard()
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Go!')
        p = get_pitch()
    
        if p == x:
            display_correct_card()
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            display_incorrect_card()
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas as why it is not recording audio in the second file and instead is only recording air?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, but I’m still not sure why it was a problem. In one of the functions, I had passed in another function as a default argument. For some reason, this was not working in the context of the larger overall program. When I stored it in a variable, then passed in the return value to the other function, everything worked as expected.